# Q.Promise: How to throw exception in callback correctly?

Tags: javascript, q

My simple code here http://jsfiddle.net/xh6960fo/

```
function test () {
    var res = Q.defer();
    res.resolve('Hello');
    return res.promise;
};

test()
.then(
    function(message) {
        console.log(message);
        throw new Error('Exception!');
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('no');
        console.error(err);
    })
.fin(function () {
    console.log('fin');
});
```

I need to raise exception in 'then' callback.

But in console I see only

> Hello
>
> fin

My exception not raising. How to throw exception correctly?

Comment: Your code can only ever log Hello, fin - what else did you expect?

Comment: @JaromandaX Do you see ```throw new Error('Exception!')?```

Comment: yes, do you know how promises work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `then`'s exception handler only catches errors that occur *before* its own success handler, not including.

```
...
.then(function() {
    throw new Error('error'):
})
.then(null, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
.fin(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Cannot find this in tutorials. But how uncomfortable :(